# Traditional black console window in eclipse

Tags: java, console, window

Is it possible to display the traditional black pop-up console window while testing an app in Eclipse
instead of the built-in console window (or both)? **(for Windows)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but you should have a look to this plugin developped by Alex Ruiz from Google : http://code.google.com/p/elt/

Here is the related article : http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=2428

Please note it is Mac and Linux only.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have a solution for linux.

[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=743131) is written what might be what you're searching for:

> open up your console, check which file it is with "who" on the
>   commandline, and then under "Run" > "Open Debug Dialog" > "Common" >
>   "Check 'File'", put the file for the newly opened console there
>   (example: /dev/pts/0) and start debugging.  all your output will also
>   be written to that console now.